# Web App Bot does not contain the LUIS template for C#

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to [integrate a fully tested LUIS app to a web app bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/integrate-qnamaker-luis). 
After [creating a language understanding bot with bot service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-csharp-tutorial-build-bot-framework-sample#create-a-language-understanding-bot-with-bot-service) I tried to [connect the LUIS app to the bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-csharp-tutorial-build-bot-framework-sample#connect-your-luis-app-to-the-bot) but I could not find any of the LUIS-related entries in the application settings, which according to the tutorial should be:

[image: Luis App ID]

Furthermore, after [building the bot code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-csharp-tutorial-build-bot-framework-sample#modify-the-bot-code), I could not find the

> /Dialogs/BasicLuisDialog.cs

in the code editor.

The file structure in my editor looks like this:

[image]

It looks as if the WebAppBot does not contain the LUIS template at all.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: `could not find the /Dialogs/BasicLuisDialog.cs` Can you provide the screenshots of the project folder structure in online code editor?

Comment: `It looks as if the WebAppBot does not contain the LUIS template at all.` Please check if the SDK version you selected is v3 when you choose Bot template.

Comment: @FeiHan: Done. See above for the folder structure.

Comment: Apparently, I had used sdk v4 before. After setting up a new bot using sdk 3, I get the LUIs entries. If you post that as an answer , I can accept it.

Comment: OK, I will post it as a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It looks as if the WebAppBot does not contain the LUIS template at all.

Based on the project folder structure that you see in online code editor, it seems that you are using SDK v4.

[image]

Currently, Auzre portal enables us to use Language understanding (c#) template with **SDK v3**.

[image]

Comment: I still don't find the /Dialogs/BasicLuisDialog.cs in the Explorer, after executing "build.cmd" :-(

Comment: After you created the bot with Language understanding (c#) template, if not execute "build.cmd", does `BasicLuisDialog.cs` exist under your project dialog folder?

Comment: What are folders/files in wwwroot folder?

Comment: See the last screenshot in the updated question - it pretty much shows them all. Just the .vs and the bin folders are missing, but they dont contain that file either.

Comment: Did you click [Select button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrfIP.png) instead of closing it directly after you selected Language understanding (c#) template?

Comment: My bad: I built it again, and the Dialog.cs is there!